# hasClass() not evaluating true in setInterval

Tags: jquery, facebook, setinterval

Ok so here's my problem:
I'm trying to trigger a redirect by checking whether a Facebook like button has been clicked.
If it has been clicked, then I can just keep checking whether a certain div has a certain class. If it evaluates true at any point, it will fire the redirect.
But it's not doing that.

Reason I'm using setInterval is that it must check this on page load, and continuously, in case they've already liked it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="pluginConnectButton">

<div title="" class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginConnectButtonDisconnected hidden_elem">
    <div>
    <button type="submit">
    <i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like sx_like_fav"></i>Like
    </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div title="" class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonPressed pluginButtonX pluginConnectButtonConnected">

<div>
<button type="submit">
<i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOff img sp_like sx_like_ch"></i>
<i title="" class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOn img sp_like sx_like_x"></i>
</button>Like
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS/jQuery:

```
setInterval(

function(){
if ($('div.pluginConnectButton div').eq(0).hasClass('hidden_elem')) {

    window.open('http://thebasinhaircutters.com.au/competitions/abd/m/next.php', '_parent');

}}

,1000);
```

Comment: Can you not use the javascript SDK and subscribe to the edge.create event https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: If that `if` test is true, won't it keep opening additional windows every second?

Comment: No it doesn't create new windows, it opens in the existing window (redirect, not popup).

Comment: @TommyBs, no, I cannot use that. I need to fire the event if someone has already pressed the like button or liked the page. This is essentially a custom fan-gate.

Answer (score 1):

It works based on this test?

```
var interval = null;
$(function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
    if($('input').hasClass('clicked')) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert('I\'ve been clicked!');​​
    } else {
        console.log('I\'ve not been clicked');
    }
    }, 1000);
    $('input').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
});
​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/8ZXba/

Keep an eye on the console to see it going through each interval and then on clicking the button, the alert will show.

Comment: This will not work if they reload the page or visit it a second time.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your question where you specify that it should?

Comment: Have added that now. The setInterval function would be pointless if I didn't want that functionality though.

Comment: The Facebook like button retains it's state after it's clicked (and after subsequent refreshes), so the `pluginButtonPressed` class should  exist as the button is clicked and then each time the page is refreshed until you click the like button again. As a result, the above script will work until it finds the input element with a `clicked` class.

Comment: This will not work. I don't want to assign a new class. I want to use the existing class "hidden_elem". If the selected element has that class, fire redirect... simple?